# Loopcut not working

Tags: mesh

I have been trying for hours now with no solution, when I press ctrl + r my loopcuts wont appear, the loopcutting just never enables, I checked to make sure the hotkeys are correct, and I reinstalled blender, I really need help on this, thank you.

Comment: it's probably a matter of topology, please show some screenshots of the object

Comment: I used the basic cube, and the default objects....

Comment: Have you checked that the keymap hasn't been accidentally modified? Is the shortcut listed in *Edit > Preferences > Keymap* (select *Key-Binding* in the search).

Comment: I searched it up there and nothing popped up when I searched up loopcuts in keybinding

Comment: which version of blender are you working with?

Comment: Just try to move your cursor around the cube after pressing Ctrl + R.  Sometime it doesn't show up.  Sometimes I also have this problem I'm using 2.90.

Comment: are you in Edit mode at least?

Comment: Silly question, but: You did move your mouse over an edge, right?